# Hello, on ReactJs, I loose focus on input when useState change value :

Tags: reactjs

Here an example of the problem :
[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-haze-d2onfr?file=/src/App.js)

```
export default function App() {

  const [hasInputChanged, setHasInputChanged] = useState(false);

  let colorList = ["orange", "blue", "yellow"];

  function handleChange(e) {
    setHasInputChanged(true);
  }

  const MyLittleInput = () => {
    return <input onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)} />;
  };

  return (
    <>
      {colorList.map((color) => (
        <MyLittleInput key={color} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
  
}
```

I tried different solutions as defining Keys or using useRef but nothing worked

Comment: Thank you for providing a sandbox! What are the exact steps to reproduce the problem? It's not very clear.

Comment: Please put a [mre], **as text**, in the question itself. I'd recommend taking the [tour] and reading [ask].

Answer (score 0):

It's too much code to be debugged easily, but for what I can see on the fiddle, there are serveral things wrong, first of all you are doing really too much things for a simple increment/decrement of a input value. But most important you are defining theyr value using the `parametresListe` state, but never really changing it wit the `setParametresListe` function, which should be the only way to safely change controlled form inputs.

Just try to do a bit of cleaning on your code and to use the `useState` as it is meat to be used

Let us know any updates!

UPDATE:
Having a look at your cleaned code, the problem is that a input inside a component gets builded again and again.
The reason for that, is that each input should have they unique "key" prop, so react can easily understand what input is changed and update only that one.
You have 2 ways to make this work, for the first, I've edited your code:

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";

const DEFAULT_INPUT_STATE = {
  orange: "",
  blue: "",
  yellow: ""
};
export default function App() {
  let colorList = ["orange", "blue", "yellow"];
  const [inputState, setInputState] = useState(DEFAULT_INPUT_STATE);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    console.log(name);

    setInputState({
      ...inputState,
      [name]: value
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      {colorList.map((color, i) => (
        <input
          key={color}
          name={color}
          value={inputState[color]}
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
        />
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

As you can see, I've just removed the component for the input and did a bit of other changes, but If you still want to use a component, you can moove all the `.map` function inside of it, but there's no way to create the input inside a component if it is in a `.map` function

Comment: I cleaned it ;)

Comment: Comment updated! :)